# Как отобразить страницы в bitrix?

Tags: php, битрикс

Проблема началась с того как я стал редактировать страницу "NanoCAD"(скриншот 1)
Потом изменил страницу в визуальном редакторе, просто удалив компонент "меню" (скрины 2 и 3)
В итоге не могу зайти ни на одну страницу раздела "каталог", просто пустой белый экран (скрин 4). Хотя данные страницы содержат контент, я проверил.
Очень нужен ваш совет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Белая страница - результат не обработанной ошибки. Добавьте код ниже в init.php. Внимание! Этот код только для отладки, не используйте его в продакшене.

```
register_shutdown_function(function(){
    if(!defined('START_EXEC_EPILOG_AFTER_1')){
        require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].BX_ROOT."/modules/main/include/epilog_after.php");
    }
});
```